# Find pdf of X+Y

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution, convolution

Let X ∼ Exp(λ) and Y ∼ Exp(μ) be two independent exponential random variables,
where λ, μ > 0.
Find the probability density function of X + Y if λ ̸= μ.

I have successfully find ans if λ = μ, but stuck when finding pdf of X+Y if λ ̸= μ

Answer (score 0):

The sum of exponential distributions each with it's own parameter turns out to be a hypoexponential distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoexponential_distribution).

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \text{Exp}(\lambda_i) \sim \text{Hypoexponential}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$$

assuming $\lambda_i>0$.